# I want to find a user who tried 3 logins in 5 minutes. in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

this data in mysql5.7

I want to find a user who tried 3 logins in 5 minutes.

Is this possible with mysql query?

```
+----+--------+----------------------+
| id |  type  |         date         |
+----+--------+----------------------+
| a  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:01:00  |
| a  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:07:00* |
| a  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:10:00* |
| b  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:00:00  |
| b  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:10:00  |
| b  | logout | 2019-10-17 10:20:00  |
| a  | logout | 2019-10-17 10:11:00* |
| a  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:11:30* |
| b  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:10:00  |
| c  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:08:00  |
| c  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:27:00* |
| b  | logout | 2019-10-17 10:30:00  |
| c  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:30:00* |
| c  | login  | 2019-10-17 10:31:00* |
+----+--------+----------------------+
```

I want to get following result:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id | type   | count |
+----+--------+-------+
| a  | login  |   4   |
| c  | login  |   3   |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Here are the table structure and data example;

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
`id` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


    --
    -- Dumping data for table `a`
    --


INSERT INTO `a` VALUES 
('a','login','2019-10-17 10:01:00'),
('a','login','2019-10-17 10:07:00'),
('a','login','2019-10-17 10:10:00'),
('b','login','2019-10-17 10:00:00'),
('b','login','2019-10-17 10:10:00'),
('b','logout','2019-10-17 10:20:00'),
('a','logout','2019-10-17 10:11:00'),
('a','login','2019-10-17 10:11:30'),
('b','login','2019-10-17 10:10:00'),
('c','login','2019-10-17 10:08:00'),
('c','login','2019-10-17 10:27:00'),
('b','logout','2019-10-17 10:30:00'),
('c','login','2019-10-17 10:30:00'),
('c','login','2019-10-17 10:31:00');
```

Comment: Do the three tries have to be consecutive? Eg if there is a logout in between, should we reset the login counter?

Comment: And how does `a` have a count of "2"?

Comment: Okay. Even if not continuous.

Comment: count was modified.

Comment: shouldn't `a` login count is 3? because the other one is logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**complete query**

```
select t1.id, t1.type, count(*) ct
from a t1
left join a t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.date >= date_add(t1.date, interval 5 minute)
where t2.type = 'login' and t1.type = 'login'   
group by t1.id, t1.type
having count(1) >= 3
```

See [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=Q3TA950mCt)

Comment: mysql> select id, type, count(1) from a
    -> where type = 'login'
    -> group by UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) div 300, id, type
    -> having count(1) = 3;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: @user1819769, seems your date is varchar? I updated the answer, you can also try dbfiddle i provided

Comment: @user1819769, i have updated the answer count() for a should be equal to 3

Answer (score 0):

Use group by id and count(*) with having

Comment: select  id, type, count(id) from table group by id, type having count(*) = 3

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the count is.  But you can do:

```
select distinct id
from t
where t.type = 'login' and
      (select count(*)
       from t t2
       where t2.type = 'login' and
             t2.date >= t.date and
             t2.date < t.date + interval 5 minute
      ) >= 3;
```